# Why my cellar changed and now is full of spider webs?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

My basement cellar texture changed and now rooms are full of spider webs and fast annoying spiders. What's happened? Any hints how to go back and how to kill these spiderlings?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the DLC, there is always a chance of entering alternate versions of levels:

- Basement = Cellar
- Caves = Catacombs
- Depths = Necropolis
- Womb = Utero
- Sheol = Cathedral

At the end of Womb/Utero, you have a choice of entering Sheol or Cathedral.
All the other floors are random.

Answer (score 1):

This probably happened because you bought the DLC. Wrath of the Lamb adds alternates for each floor, including harder enemies as above, and there is no way (as far as I know) to go back. As for avoiding/killing the spiders, my main tip is to keep moving, and try not to get close enough to trigger their chasing mode (where they stop moving randomly and instead move toward you). Also, be careful and watch the "beat" of when they do their little movement spurts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a random occurrence, and each floor has an alternate.  (Basement;cellar, Caves;catacombs, depths;necropolis, Womb;Utero, Sheol;Cathedral). You can choose between Sheol and the Cathedral.  However the new enemies will take quite a while to adjust to.

You have no control over any floors other than Sheol/Cathedral.